# C# and special characters

Tags: c#, html, character, special-characters, html-agility-pack

I use `htmlagility` to read `html` file and extract some data . in Danish language we have some special characters like ( å Å - æ Æ - ø Ø ) . But in c# i get another character instead of them . As you can see in the picture , instead of "Køkkenredskaber IVS"  i have something else . How can i get the exact character ?

[image]

Comment: That <?> character is a placeholder for a character that can't be represented in the [display typeface](https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5054/5547461213_237e82b9fd.jpg). Apart from hover text/code insight in Visual Studio, is this causing any other problems?

Comment: @BobKaufman  Yes for example in database  instead of exact character i have  "?"  .   Even we have a logger and it logs the name  with same problem .

Comment: I think it uses iso-8859-1

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make sure your database is set up to store the correct charset. I think if you use nvarchar() instead of varchar(), you will find that it will work.

I had a similar problem when storing Hebrew characters in a database, and this fixed it for me.